# Trying to find fantasy book about people who could transform into dragons

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book but I cannot remember the name of it the author or any of the characters' names.

I do remember that:

- The main character is a female lead

  - She has a magical tattoo on her back
- It takes place in a medieval fantasy setting
- There are many characters with the ability to transform into dragons.
- The book is one of a series but I do not know the series length (though I am sure it is more than three books)

  - The first one starts out with the lead living in a village being raised by a wizard. Later, after meeting with several of these dragon shifters the lead leaves her home to travel with them.
  - The antagonist in the series is another dragon shifter who I believe throughout the books is after them and frequently contacts the lead through magic.
  - The lead will also develop powers in the book and the tattoo on her back will change as the powers form and she accepts them - though the powers will also come with their own personalities.

Any help in finding this book series will be greatly appreciated even if it leads nowhere.

Comment: When did you read this? When do you think it might have been published? Also, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: I read it several years ago but I cannot remember the date of publication but I it cannot have been published after 2015