# Book that has people that turn into dragons and the people have dragon tattoos

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was shown to me a while ago and I've been trying to look for it. It’s a series and the one I remember seeing had a red spine and a white cover with a flying dragon on it.

Comment: Is this the same book? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158791/82909